# wondering why the result of these two is different?

Tags: python, for-loop, random, range

I am wondering why the result of these two is different?

```
import random
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)
for i in range(7):
  print(secretNumber)

import random
for i in range(7):
  print(random.randint(1, 20))
```

but the other side the result of these two is same:

```
number = range(1,7)
for i in number: print(i)

for i in range(1,7): print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is set to a variable meaning the value will be constant/same. Second one gets different value on every loop because you're generating a different random number on every loop.

```
import random
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)
for i in range(7):
  print(secretNumber) # secretNumber will always be the same

import random
for i in range(7):
  print(random.randint(1, 20)) # will generate random number every loop
```

Comment: OK Thaks. I am trying to get your point but confusion is why the result of these two is same:

number = range(1,7)
for i in number:
  print(i)

for i in range(1,7):
  print(i)

Comment: I edited my question to make it clear what is my confusion is.

Comment: Saw it, first one you set it to a variable. Second one is not inside a loop that's why it has the same value. It's like the first one but you didn't put it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some comments to the code so that you can decipher what's happening.

```
import random

# run random.randint(1,20) method 1 time and store the value in variable secretNumber
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

for i in range(7):
  # Print the variable secretNumber 7 times (value is some integer)
  print(secretNumber) 

# Do whatever is in this loop 7 times
for i in range(7):
  # Print the value returned by random.randint(1,20)
  print(random.randint(1, 20))

# store range object (which is merely an iterator) in variable number
number = range(1,7)

# for loop will iterate the object stored in variable number
for i in number:
    print(i)

# range(1,7) will always return the same object so number === range(1,7)
for i in range(1,7):
    print(i)
```

More information on how range works in Python 3 vs 2 [Assign a range to a variable (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177919/assign-a-range-to-a-variable-python)