# 'range' object does not support item assignment int assignment to array

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am try to run a image encrypt program the original program was in 2.7 after removing most of the error i am stuck with this piece of code

the original link for the project file is https://github.com/AtheMathmo/ImageEncryptor/blob/master/ImageEncryptor/utils.py

had tried the list(p)

```
def main():
start = time.time()
two_kdp(25000, 12412513, 345987439589897)
end = time.time()
print (end - start)
```

def two_kdp(size, k1, k2):

```
# Initialization
y = 1
z = 1
p = k1 * k2

C = list(range(len(size)))

# Generate set
for i in range(size):
    w = y + (k2 + i)
    x = z + (k1 + i)

    y += w
    z += x + y

    p = (p + y + z) % size

    C[i] = int(p) (stuck at this point)
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you really want to accomplish here and where you are stuck?

Comment: updated the code had tried C = list(range(size))

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. Append each element inside a for loop.

```
C = []
C.append(1)
C
[1]
```

Or take a look at here:

[range to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177919/assign-a-range-to-a-variable-python)